# Get waveforms like sound cloud

Tags: javascript, php

I am using [Waves](https://github.com/boyhagemann/Wave) to get the amplitudes from a wav file and then i want to put the amplitudes array in the `waveform` proprety of this [soundcloud-waveform](https://github.com/olivierrr/soundcloud-waveform), but the waveform proprety is in `float` and i dont get it how waveform array works.

```
        $wave = new Wave();
        $wave->setSteps(100);
        $wave->setFilename('file.wav');
        $data = $wave->getWaveformData();

        foreach($data->getChannels() as $channel) {
            $amplitudes[] = $channel->getValues();
                                                    }

            $vari=102;
        $new_times[] =0.07857142857142857;
        foreach ( $amplitudes[0] as $value) {

                            if ($value>=0){
                                $new_times[] = $value /10000000000;
                            }
             $vari+=4008;



            }
          foreach ( $amplitudes[1] as $value) {

                            if ($value>=0){
                                $new_times[] = $value /10000000000;
                            }
             $vari+=4008;



            }

    ?>

    <script >
        window.o = new WAVEFORM({
        container: newDiv(),
        waveform: <?php echo json_encode($new_times);?>,
        height: 200,
        width: 800,
        trackLength: 120,
        reflection: 0.3,
        waveWidth: 2
    }).....
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i wanna know how to use the waveform proprety from the javascript in the bottom, its using"https://github.com/olivierrr/soundcloud-waveform". And get the amplitudes from "https://github.com/boyhagemann/Wave" and put in waveform proprety trough php.

Comment: That's not a question. What isn't working?